# Semantic UI change closable setting dynamically

Tags: javascript, semantic-ui

I want to change the modal's closable setting after it opens but I can't.

When I click closable button in the modal, the black background can't clickable. I use this code but it doesn't work properly.

```
$(".ui.modal").modal("setting", "closable", true).modal("show");
```

How can I make clickable background?

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NNZRxb

Comment: Can you please expand the question? Is it that on clicking background you want to close the modal or clicking on close-modal button need to close the modal?

Comment: I have an unclosable modal. When you open it you can't close by clicking outside or pressing ESC. After I run some JS codes I want to close the modal by clicking dimmer or pressing ESC. Try to open the modal and press ESC and click dimmer. It doesn't work because the modal unclosable. After that, click closable=true button. And now if you press the ESC key the modal can close but if you click the dimmer modal can't close. I want to close modal by clicking dimmer.

Comment: Here, do you want to close the modal on clicking dimmer on 1st click or after clicking the closable=true button??

Comment: I want to activate it after clicking the closable=true button.

Answer (score 0):

This is an existing bug. A PR exists to fix this but it was never merged:

https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/pull/3396